# Can I show a PDF inside a DIV with a zoom function?

Tags: pdf, object, zooming

I have a large PDF and I need to show it 50% reduced in size inside a div tag that is 600px 600px in size.  I also need to offer the client a zoom function.

Should I use the "object" tag?  But can I reduce the pdf size inside an "object"?

Is there a jquery example or anything out there?

Need help.

Comment: you can use Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PDFs cannot be displayed in a DIV, as they're not html or an image. You can convert the PDF to html/images on the server and display that, just like google's "quick view" function does. But in general, PDF rendering in-browser is dependent on the presence of a plugin (e.g. Adobe Reader, Chrome's built-in rendering engine notwithstanding). Plugins can't be displayed in divs, just embed/object/iframe sections.

Comment: But what about in an `<object>` section - I am experiencing same issue as Erik, can't adjust zoom of PDF even within object tag.  I asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917007/zoom-and-other-parameters-on-embedded-pdf-object-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <object data="febrero2012.pdf" type="application/pdf"  width="600px" height="600px">
    alt : <a href="febrero2012.pdf">febrero2012.pdf</a> 
  </object>
</div >
```

I coudn't find the way to set a default zoom level yet. If you find a way, please let me know.