# Zoom and other parameters on embedded PDF object not working

Tags: html, pdf, embed

I am embedding a PDF using `<object>` into a page.  I want the PDF to display as only a portion of the page, and I would like for the whole first page to show in the visible area (similar to an image snapshot of the first page). I am working with the [PDF open parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf) and I see various examples for adjusting `zoom` and `view`, for example:

- `http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3&zoom=200,250,100`
- `http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=72&view=fitH,100`

I can't get these to work.  When I change the `page` parameter, the page displayed changes, but I cannot figure out how to adjust the view.

**[JS Fiddle demo showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/kg28naow/2/)**. And an example of the embed code:

```
<object width="300" height="375" type="application/pdf" data="file.pdf?#page=2&zoom=100">
    <p>Message for non-compatible browsers</p>
</object>
```

I saw this question: [Initial Zoom Parameter for PDF Object in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938141/initial-zoom-parameter-for-pdf-object-in-html5), but the answers did not help me.

Comment: Which PDF viewers or plugins do you want to support?

Comment: I am not sure - I assume Adobe and I saw a reference to Google Chrome.  Are there others? Adding params for Chrome noted in other question don't seem to change anything for me.